# Get Data from Array by Variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, offset

I have this array:

```
$array = array();
 $array['123'] = 'abc';
 $array['456'] = 'def';
```

Now I would like to get data from that array based on a variable. This is what I tried:

```
$variable = '123';    
$result = $array[$variable];
echo $result;
```

It appears to be wrong, but i don't know why. It results in a warning:

```
Illegal offset type […]
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Are you sure you have nothing else going on?

Comment: The illegal offset type usually occurs when you try and use an object or an array as the key for accessing an array, you sure that's the code you're using?

Comment: Yes and no: $variable is created from another array variable ($variable = $post['id'];)

Comment: This outputs "abc" for me with no warnings.

Comment: `var_dump($variable);` outputs...?

Comment: Try `var_dump($post['id'])` or `var_dump($variable)` and look/post the result.

Comment: I also ran the code successfully; so probably from above I would assume $post['id'] is not exactly '123'. Did you mean $_POST['id'] like you just got the data from a form? Try to echo $post['id'] before it's use to see what it actually is, if it is the same please post the code that defines the value of $post['id'].

Comment: try `var_dump($post['id'])` - or did you mean `$_POST['id']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran that exact code into my compiler and it worked; possibly it is a white-space error (random characters you cant see but still cause bugs). I would try to physically retype that section of code and delete the old one.

Comment: $variable is created from another array variable ($variable = $post['id'];) - could that cause the problem?

Comment: Add a line where you echo $post['id']; and see what it says.  If $post['id'] is equal to 123 or similar you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: I agree with Michael. I advised to try the same method in a comment to your question.

Comment: solution: had to convert the variable to integer: $variable = (int)$variable; - thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: It's probably safer to do it as a string as I put in my answer, because if your post ID is something weird like 1.1 converting it to an int will cause it to lose important information.  Also you should mark someone's answer as correct so other people know it is solved and don't bother reading it.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying this to make sure the variable is cast as a string:

```
$result = $array[(string)$variable];
```

That's most likely your problem.  I think maybe $post['id'] is either mistakenly a multi-dimensional array or somehow becoming an object of a type not accepted as an array key.